# Compare the Active Configuration to a Previous Configuration Juniper Ansible - junipernetworks.junos.junos

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, juniper, juniper-network-connect

I want to get output of Before and After Configuration commits to device.

Ansible Code :

```
- name: Get device information
  hosts: working_hosts
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    ansible_network_os: junipernetworks.junos.junos
    connection_info:
      port: '{{ ansible_ssh_port }}'
      user: '{{ ansible_ssh_user }}'
      passwd: '{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}'
      
  tasks:
    - name: load configure lines into device and commit to device
      junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
        update: 'merge'
        lines:
        - set security address-book global address 10.xxx.x.xxx 10.xxx.x.xxx/xx

        check_commit: yes
        confirm_commit: yes
      register: junos_output
      diff: true

    - debug:
        var: junos_output
```

Below output not showing diff between previous and current committed configurations, help me if i am doing any thing wrong here.

Output:

```
ok: [xx.xx.xxx.xx] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "backup": false,
            "backup_options": null,
            "check_commit": true,
            "comment": "configured by junos_config",
            "confirm": 0,
            "confirm_commit": false,
            "lines": [
                "set security address-book global address 10.xxx.x.xxx 10.xxx.x.xxx/xx"
            ],
            "provider": null,
            "replace": null,
            "rollback": null,
            "src": null,
            "src_format": null,
            "update": "merge",
            "zeroize": false
        }
    }
}
```

We can compare the candidate configuration to a previously committed configuration by using the following commands:

```
show | compare rollback rollback-number

show | compare rollback 1
```

Output:

```
[edit security address-book global]
+    address xx.xxx.xx.xx { ... }
+    address xx.xxx.xx.xx {
+        xx.xxx.x.xxx/xx;
+    }
```

I can able to get output as expected using juniper.device.config module but i need it with junipernetworks.junos.junos_config module.

```
- name: Print diff between current and rollback 1. No check. No commit.
  juniper.device.config:
    rollback: 1
    diff: true
    check: false
    commit: false
  register: response

- name: Print the msg.
  debug:
    var: response.diff_lines
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue somehow with multiple tries.

```
- name: Load configure lines into device
  junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
    lines:
      - set security address-book global address 10.xxx.x.xxx 10.xxx.x.xxx/xx

    confirm_commit: yes
  register: device_status
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Compare rollback the configuration
  junipernetworks.junos.junos_config:
    rollback: 1
    check_commit: no
    confirm_commit: no
  diff: yes
  register: status_message
  when: device_status.failed is false
```

this gives me recent committed output on the device.